# DevExpress GridControl add custom footer

Tags: devexpress

Здравствуйте.
Имеется некоторая переменная Sum, которая по некоторой формуле ведет рассчет на основе столбца colTotal.
Стандартными средствами можно расположить на footer подсчитанное значение Sum под столбцом colTotal.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли Sum расположить на footer, не привязываясь к колонке colTotal, а расположив в начале грида и растянув ячейку со значением Sum на всю ширину грида? (изменение ширины колонок не будет влиять на ширину ячейки со значением Sum).

Answer (score 2):

Решение для такой задачи это взять и отрисовать ячейку самому. Используй GridView.CustomDrawFooterCell событие для этого. Можешь вот тут про это почитать

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3028

А так если есть лицензия, пиши в поддержку. Тебе точно помогут.